# How could I send email from local development without using Mail::pretend() in 4.2?

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

My sample mail config is:

`'driver' => 'sendmail', 
 'host' => 'localhost', 
 'port' => 25,
 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'`

Mail::send throws *Swift_TransportException "The system cannot find the path specified. ]"* error. I am using Windows. I guess this happens because of my server config. How could I use this for local to test? Before people yell at me, this is client requirement to use 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maildev` server for testing mail in localhost with laravel, it's work fine for me.
config

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Install maildev to your computer

```
npm install -g maildev
```

Run maildev server

```
maildev
```

Comment: That's running good in default php mail(to, subject, message) function. When I replace with my Mail::send() function, it throws again Swift_TransportException error "Connection could not be established with host localhost [The requested address is not valid in its context. #10049]". What is this? :(

Comment: You started the maildev server before?